# Google Directory API: Requests to this API admin method are blocked

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to get the customer domain by using the [customers.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/customers/get) API. I already added the scopes in the consent screen:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.customer
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.customer.readonly

But I get this error message after do the request (looks like a permission issue):

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests to this API admin method ccc.hosted.frontend.directory.v1.DirectoryCustomers.Get are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests to this API admin method ccc.hosted.frontend.directory.v1.DirectoryCustomers.Get are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

For some reason, in Google's API Explorer works perfectly but not in my API Client (Insomnia) nor my web app. In my web app I set the scopes using JavaScript Client library.

Also, I'm using Google Drive, Docs APIs and those work well.

Is there something I'm missing with this API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The reason was my API key was restricted for 2 APIs in Google Console Cloud:

- Google Docs API
- Google Drive API

So I had to add the Admin SDK API to the restrict list:

[image]

After that my request works as expected. Thank you.